# Exit codes 127 and 255 in Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework, robotframework-sshlibrary

Exit Code: 255, 127 returned when ssh is used to execute a command in a remote server in RobotFramework. The command is not inbuilt command but the absolute path is provided.

```
*** Test Cases ***
open_connection_and_login
    Open Connection  ${HOST}
    Login  ${USERNAME}  ${PASSWORD}
    ${res}=  Execute Commmand  cmd test.qoc
    log to console  ${res}
    Close All Connections
```

cmd is a command which is not built-in shell command

Comment: There is not enough detauls, please, provide command you are running and returned error, So we can at least see entire process of your workflow

Comment: Command being executed is not a built-in shell command.

Comment: Most likely it is failing because either the command doesn't exist, or the command isn't in your path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To execute commands that are not built-in. Directly write them to the terminal using "Write" keyword.

Use Write keyword in SSHLibrary. It pastes the command on the terminal and the command gets executed.